# Iterating Videos

Tags: swift, video, avplayer

I am trying to get the player to iterate through an array of strings that reference the URL of  videos. I can only get it to play one of the videos in the array, if I hardcode it in the code, but I cannot do it to iterate.

I have gotten to play one video while it is hard coded in but not iterate.

```
   var playerArray = [AVQueuePlayer]()
    var player = AVQueuePlayer()
   // var URLSArray = [URL]()
    var ItemArray = [AVPlayerItem]()

    var videos = ["video1", "video2","video3"]

    var playerController = AVPlayerViewController()




override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let videoNum = (self.videos.count-1)

  //  var URLSArray = [URL]()

 //   for n in 0...videoNum{
 //       let pathString = (Bundle.main.path(forResource: videos[n], ofType: "mov"))
  //      let StrToURL  = NSURL(string: pathString!)
  //      URLSArray.append(StrToURL! as URL)

 //   }

    var ItemArray = [AVPlayerItem]()
 //  var playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

    for n  in 0...videoNum{
        let pathString = (Bundle.main.path(forResource: videos[n], ofType: "mov"))

        //print(pathString!)
        let StrToURL  = URL(string: pathString!)
       // print(StrToURL!)
       // ItemArray = [AVPlayerItem(url: StrToURL!)]
        ItemArray.append(AVPlayerItem(url:StrToURL!))
        print(n)
        print(ItemArray)
       // let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: ItemArray[0])

        player = AVQueuePlayer(items: [ItemArray[n]])


        player.play()
                   }




             //  playerController.player = player
              // present(playerController, animated: true) {
                //   player.play()

    }
```

I want it to finish playing one video and move on to the next video in the array, how ever I hard code the video from the array it works but if I am trying to iterate it acts as if the URL isn't working. This is what it says 2019-06-14 13:08:44.718684-0400 Video[5439:1288491] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002

Comment: Hi there, could you show the inputs and outputs and clean up your code listings to remove the unused code? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Declare only the player

```
var player = AVQueuePlayer()
```

In `viewDidAppear` map the string array to the URLs in the application bundle and then the URLs to the player items. Then create the queued player and start playing.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let videos = ["video1", "video2", "video3"]
    let videoURLs = videos.compactMap{ Bundle.main.url(forResource: $0, withExtension: "mov")}
    let itemArray = videoURLs.map{ AVPlayerItem(url: $0) }

    player = AVQueuePlayer(items: itemArray)
    player.play()

    //  playerController.player = player
    // present(playerController, animated: true) {
    //   player.play()
    // }
}
```

Comment: Now it isn't giving me an error but it still isn't playing the video either, I have used AVQueuePlayer(items: itemArray) and I am wondering and researching if it needs a layer ?